# Hide remove X on lightning:pill/pillcontainer

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-base-component

Is there any way to disable or hide (even just by using CSS) the remove X from lightning:pill?

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:pill/documentation) seems to indicated that as it says "by default":

> By default, pills are rendered with a remove button.

I even tried to hide them using this CSS but it didn't work:

```
.THIS .slds-pill_container .slds-pill__remove {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure there's a way to this. It kind of feels like an obvious oversight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
.THIS .slds-pill__remove {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Should also work without marking the class as `!important` and with higher specificity.

Comment: @Raul yes I agree. :)

Comment: Did you try this out? I tried with higher specificty AND important and it did not work.

Comment: I have posted after testing only

Comment: this works, but it is applied to all pill container fields. how to achieve this for speicific field?

Answer (score 1):

In your LWC/component, if you know you don't want an 'X', use a lightning-badge instead in a repeating template block iterating through the items. Using css, you can make it look exactly like a pill without an 'X' by adding this class:

```
.mybadge {margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: unset;
    padding: 3px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For LWC:

```
.slds-pill__remove {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: tried this for LWC but not working. Also tried with .slds-button_icon class